# When i write equations in beamer i'm facing so many errors with \end{frame}

Tags: beamer, equations

```
\begin{frame}
\subsection{Grouping of candidate nodules}
\frametitle{\begin{center}
        Grouping of candidate nodules
\end{center}}
\begin{equation*}
$$ NoduleThickness = Total number of slices having that nodule $$
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
$$ \% wallconnectivity  = \frac{No.of slices with wall connected nodule region\times 100}{Nodule Thickness} $$
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
```

error

```
Missing $ inserted. \end{frame}
Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{frame}
```

please help

Comment: sorry my code posted in misorder

Comment: Welcome, If you mark the code and click on the little brace icon, it will be highlighted. Alternatively mark the code and hit `CTRL + k`.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please always post full minimal examples not sniplets, (3) that code would not have worked anywhere, beamer or not. Start by removing all the `$$`. You should also learn to use align from the amsmath package and the subsection goes outside the frame.

Answer (score 3):

you have bunch of problems:

- nesting equations in equation: `\begin{equation}$$ ...$$\equation}` is wrong
- sections, subsections ... should be (usual are) outside of frames
- use only `\subsection{...}` in presentation doesn't work. before it should be somewhere `\section{...}`
- text in equation had to be declared as text, otherwise latex consider it as long series of variables ...
- your equations are to long to fit in frame, so you need to consider to write text in fraction in two lines:
- centering of frame title. the way as you do is wrong. you should adequately define beamer template (see *mwe* below)
- helping you would be much easier if you provided a complete, small document, we call it *mwe*, which begins with `\documentclass{beamer}`, ends with `\end{document}`, with loaded all relevant packages in preamble and yours `beamer` settings and other (only relevant) definitions. help us help you!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
    {
    \begin{centering}
    \insertframetitle\par
    \end{centering}
    }
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\section{had to be somewhere before subsections}
\subsection{Grouping of candidate nodules}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Grouping of candidate nodules}
\[
\text{NoduleThickness} = \text{Total number of slices having that nodule}
\]
\[
\% wallconnectivity  = \frac{\splitfrac{\text{No. of slices with wall}}
                                       {\text{connected nodule region}}\times 100}
                            {\text{Nodule Thickness}}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]